# What can be the possible logic for printing this pattern in Java(BlueJ)?

Tags: java, bluej

Note: '#' represents 'space' here.
Below is the code snippet showing how I've tried to write the program:-

```
//Pattern to be printed:-
    /* ##1
     * #121
     * 12321
     * #121
     * ##1
       */
    for(int i=n;i>=1;i--)
    {
        for(int j=n-3;j>=0;j--)
        {
           System.out.print(" ");
           for(int k=i-2;k>=1;k--)
           {
               System.out.print(k);
           }
           System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
int i,s,k,j;
for (i=1;i<=5;i++) //for 5 loops
{
    for (s=1;s<=5-i;s++) //for spaces
    {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (j=1;j<=i;j++)
    {
        System.out.print(j); //for printing values
    }
    for (k=i-1;k>=1;k--)
    {
        System.out.print(k); //for printing values
    }
    System.out.println(); //for line break
}
for (i=4;i>=1;i--) //for 4 loops
{
    for (s=1;s<=5-i;s++) //for spaces
    {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (j=1;j<=i;j++)
    {
        System.out.print(j); //for printing values
    }
    for (k=i-1;k>=1;k--)
    {
        System.out.print(k); //for printing values
    }
    System.out.println(); //for line break
}
```

The Output Will be :

```
    1
   121
  12321
 1234321
123454321
 1234321
  12321
   121
    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `max` value if you want a different size diamond

```
public class Pattern {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int max = 3;

    // Draw triangle
    for (int i = max; i >= 0; i--) {
      foo(max-i, max);
    }

    // Draw upside down triangle
    for (int i = 1; i < max; i++) {
      foo(max-i, max);
    }
  }

  public static void foo(int n, int max) {

    // Put spaces to center it
    for (int i = 0; i < max-n; i++) {
      System.out.print(" ");
    }

    // Print counting up
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      System.out.print(i);
    }

    // Print counting down
    for (int i = n-1; i >= 1; i--) {
      System.out.print(i);
    }

    // New line character
    System.out.println();

  }

}
```

Output (Note there is an extra space at the top, I'll leave that as an exercise for you to try to remove):

```
  1
 121
12321
 121
  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code of what you wanted

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;


class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int n;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        n=sc.nextInt();
        int a,b;
        a=n-1;
        b=1;

        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<=a;j++)
                System.out.print("#");
            for(int k=1;k<=b;k++)
                System.out.print(k);
            for(int l=b-1;l>=1;l--)
                System.out.print(l);
            System.out.println("\n");   
            a--;
            b++;
        }

        a=1;
        b=n-1;

        for(int i=n-1;i>=1;i--)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<=a;j++)
                System.out.print("#");
            for(int k=1;k<=b;k++)
                System.out.print(k);
            for(int l=b-1;l>=1;l--)
                System.out.print(l);
            a++;
            b--;
                    System.out.println("\n");   

        }

    }
}
```

output-

```
##1

#121

12321

#121

##1
```